# Verify URL exists cloudflare snag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the function below to determine if a URL exists:

```
Public Function URLExists(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
    Dim webRequest As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD"
    Try
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(webRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        If (response.StatusCode.ToString = "OK") Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

For the most part this works as it should, but when a site is hosted through cloudflare, it does not return the page headers, which means the function returns false even if the destination URL does exist.

As an example you can use https://ezclix.club/m/1125 which redirects to a warriorplus.com website (which has cloudflare) before finally redirecting to https://ezclix.club/index.asp as the final destination which does exist, but the function returns false once it hits warriorplus which has cloudflare enabled.

Comment: The workflow is different. Something you could do is check if the ResponseUri is not the same as the RequestUri and if it is isn't then recursively return URLExists on the ResponseUri.

Comment: @David, I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you perhaps provide a working example with the URL I provided in my example?

Comment: `If (webRequest.RequestUri <> response.ResponseUri) Then : Return URLExists(response.ResponseUri) : End If`

Comment: Replace the `:` with newlines. StackOverflow only supports mini-markdown in comments.

Comment: @david, I am sorry. I still don't understand where in my code I must insert your example

Comment: Eff it, I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option you have is to check if the request URI is not the same as the response URI. If it isn't, then recursively check the response URI.

For example:

```vb
' Imports System.Net
Public Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Method = "GET"
    Try
        Dim response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        If (request.RequestUri <> response.ResponseUri) Then
            Return URLExists(response.ResponseUri.ToString())
        End If
        Return response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this function returns false on any URL

Comment: @Craig - Using the same exact link you provided in your original post returns true on my end.

Comment: my apologies. I tested it online at onecompiler and it returned false. I just created a test program in visual studio and it returns true. I am just going to test a couple of urls and if all works as it should I am going to go ahead and mark your asswer as correct. Thanks @David

Comment: Okay, unfortunately we are still not there yet. Try this link: [link](https://mybroadband.co.za/news/5g/466277-telkom-launches-5g.html). The URL exists, but the function returns false

Comment: @Craig - You really need to some basic debugging. The URL is returning a 403 response and not a 200. According to *your* business logic, that should return false.

Comment: yes you are right. Sorry about that. I was just grabbing some random urls from websites I had open. Strange that it would return a 403 Forbidden though